# What is the best way to convert "tongue-in-cheek" into an adverb?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, neologisms

I was thinking something like "tongue-in-cheekly" but it sounds awkward. Of course, alternatives are welcome, but I couldn't come up with one that conveyed the half-serious playfulness that I attribute to "tongue-in-cheek". Any thoughts?

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek can itself be used adverbially. *It was said tongue-in-cheek* or *He spoke tongue-in-cheek* are both commonly heard.

Comment: That comment should have set the matter at rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Edit: I reworked my answer, since Merriam-Webster was inconsistent between the free and unabridged versions.)

Per OxfordDictionaries.com, the adverb and adjective form of the *phrase* "tongue in cheek" **is** [tongue-in-cheek](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tongue-in-cheek?q=tongue-in-cheek) (with hyphens):

> [*as adjective*]: her delightful *tongue-in-cheek* humour
>
> [*as adverb*]: I think he was talking *tongue-in-cheek*.

Comment: The **real** question is: Should it be _tongue-in-cheekly_, or should it be _tonguely-in-cheek_?

Comment: @JohnLawler _Tongue-in-cheekily_ makes sense to me.

Comment: Thanks! I had the vague impression that it could be used directly as an adverb, as I've probably seen it used like that before, but was unsure; it could have been just my faulty memory at work :)

Comment: You're welcome. I was amazed at how inconsistent the various online dictionaries were with this phrase. Some didn't even list the adverb...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say **tichily**, though this does rather depend on people being familiar with [tichy](http://www.boatmancryptics.co.uk/index_files/WhatToExpect.html) as an "acronym" for tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: But tichy sounds too much like [_tetchy_](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tetchy?q=tetchy) to me, and someone who thought that you told them that they had said something _tetchily_ might disagree.

Comment: @Gnawme: That's probably because you're not already familiar with the term. To be fair, it's not really in the general vernacular. But it's particularly  prevalent among British crossword fans (myself being one), because it's a very suitable term for describing certain types of cryptic clues.

Comment: Ah, one of those maddeningly vague crossword puzzle clue terms...

Comment: I'd hardly say it was "vague". By the very nature of their pastime, UK cryptic crossword solvers tend to be very analytical and precise. I personally use the word in other contexts, but only with people I expect already know it (and even then, I doubt I've ever had occasion to inflect it into *tichily*). I think I've probably used it once or twice here on ELU, but in such contexts I'd always include the full form in brackets afterwards.

Comment: I meant vague in their use. I can't think of some of the vaguer examples offhand (my wife is the crossword and sudoku solver in the house), but a clue in a US crossword might be phrased, "Tokyo, once." (Which of course would probably seem precise and logical to a crossword puzzle fan.)

Comment: Assuming the answer to that is *EDO* or *YEDO*, I can't see anything "cryptic" there. A cryptic version might be *Jet to Tokyo on Southwest Airlines and stretch out (3,4)*, answer **LI + EDO + WN** (which I just found via Google). That one I wouldn't have got easily, because I've never heard of the actor *Jet Li*, and I didn't know the airline code for Southwest is *WN*.

Comment: You've plainly delved into realms of crossword puzzle solving that I've never even glimpsed.

Comment: We are a breed apart! :)

Comment: Your suggested answer I think is too localized. :)

Comment: [**:)**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54561/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-tongue-in-cheek-into-an-adverb)