# Being on the same wavelength

Tags: word-usage, terminology, phrase-origin

The usage of physics terminology outside of technically minded people seems limited. That's why I am curious about the phrase being on the same wavelength which as far as I understand is generally understood (and also exists in at least the German language)

- What is the origin of this phrase?
- Does it refer originally to interference or resonance or radio or...?
- What other physics/maths/engineering terms are used in common English language?

Comment: (3) Try to square the circle / put two and two together / not add up / do the maths / re-invent the wheel /  have a screw loose / be off one's rocker

Comment: [Not] firing on all cylinders / get one's wires crossed / 'It's not rocket science' / a cog in the machine / the ghost in the machine / a sputnik moment / a well-oiled machine / blow off steam / let off steam / run out of steam  / steam radio/typewriter / up and running / bent out of line / not the brightest bulb / not the sharpest chisel in the toolbox / light years ahead /

Answer (score 14):

*being on the same wavelength* is hardly "physics terminology" or limited to "technically minded people". Anyone who wished to listen to a radio program had to turn the dial until the receiver was on the same wavelength as the station broadcasting the program.

[image: from http://dxinternational.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/from-archives-tuning-in-longwave-bands.html]

> **on the same wavelength**
>   In complete accord, in rapport, as in *Conductor, orchestra members, soloists, and chorus all were on the same wavelength, making for a wonderful performance .* This term
>   alludes to radio waves that carry a broadcast. [First half of 1900s]
>    [American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wavelength)

Comment: Yeah, but it would be a pretty boring concert if they were all *literally* on the same wavelength (as in playing the same *note*). Except they couldn't *actually* do that with most instruments, because they'd have different harmonics mixed in with the base waveform.

Comment: Radio is electromagnetic spectrum, and it has the wavelength. Music is sound, and that's not EMS. Anyway, humans don't tune sounds by wavelength -- we come already equipped for sound communication. -- so the usage is metaphoric and recent in music, where it's very straightforwardly literal in EMS. There are waves and they can be measured and tuned -- and must be, to use radio communication.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you want to get technical about it, a radio transmission using only a single wavelength produces no sound from the receiver. As soon as the carrier is modulated to transmit the sound of the orchestra, it consists of multiple wavelengths (exactly which ones depends on the type of modulation). But at least for conventional broadcasts, we still decode them by tuning the receiver to the (single) nomimal wavelength of the carrier.

Comment: @FumbleFingers same wavelength means same station, same channel, not same note. Musicians on the same page of sheet music aren't necessarily playing the same note, but they are "on the same page."  Two people in separate rooms whose radios are tuned to the same wavelength will hear the same words and music at the same time.

Comment: @barbecue: I can't believe *three* different people think I don't understand either the physics *or* the language aspects involved here. Admittedly, until I've been goaded into it, I wouldn't have known that [the wavelength of middle "C" on a piano as it travels through air at standard temperature and pressure](https://socratic.org/questions/) is in fact about **1.3m**, but I did know that [it's varied quite a bit over time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concert_pitch#History_of_pitch_standards_in_Western_music).

Comment: @fumblefingers I think the point is that the wavelength of the music itself is not what is being described in the "same wavelength" metaphor, rather it's the radio frequency which one tunes in to listen to that music. Your comment seemed to be conflating the two separate things.

Comment: @barbecue: That first comment was intended to be [**tichy**](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/54565/2637) (tongue in cheek). But as the complete lack of support for my answer on that link would suggest, I'm not always on the same wavelength as everyone else here on ELU. So I'll shut up now.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the first sentence - *it would be a pretty boring concert if they were all literally on the same wavelength (as in playing the same note)* - is  funny. It's the *Except they couldn't actually do that ...* continuation (that, I think, makes no sense) that to me made you sound genuinely confused. (Hopefully English.SE is an OK place to over-analyse humor?)

Comment: @topo morto: The *couldn't actually* bit does make sense. If you play middle C on a stringed instrument, for example, it generates a lot of harmonics because the string also vibrates in 2, 3, 4,... sections, as well as along its entire length. You might say the one where it vibrates in *two* sections is "the same note" (but an octave higher), but that's not the case where it vibrates in *three* sections. And any given instrument produces *different* harmonics (that's why they *sound* different).

Comment: @FumbleFingers but what did you mean by "Except they couldn't actually do that with most instruments"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers because if by "do that" you mean "make different instruments produce a note relating to the same wavelength *in air*", then there's no problem with that, regardless of the different harmonic structures, because the concept of wavelength is not limited to sinusoids.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the origin is from an analogy with electromagnetic waves used in radio transmissions:

***[wavelength](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wavelength):***

> - o wave-length, 1850, "distance between peaks of a wave," from wave (n.) + length. Originally of spectra; ***radio sense is attested by 1925.***
> - ***Figurative sense of "mental harmony" is recorded from 1927, on analogy of radio waves.***

(Etymonline)

In the following ***[link](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/what-are-examples-of-idioms-related-to-science.html)***  below you can find other idiomatic expressions related to scientific contexts such as:

[image]:

> - A good example of a science-oriented idiom would be to “***blind someone with science***” which means to confuse someone with language that is highly technical. Another would be “***to have something down to a science”*** which means something is totally understood and managed extremely well.  Let’s look at more idioms that refer to science and some that are included in science jargon.

(Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, the idiom is almost certainly referring to old-time radio.  Radio bands used to be (and still are, to ham radio operators and radio engineers) identified by "wavelength" -- the length of a single wave of the radio signal.  (Among other things this related to the size of the antenna.)  Being "on the same wavelength" didn't necessarily imply being at *exactly* the same frequency, but meant that the two signals being compared were close in frequency -- there was a chance that a radio receiver could relatively easily be tuned from one to the other.